# JQM how to make a simple list without listview

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I'm just working on list and want to create a simple . But it seems that JQM set a default class="list-view" even if I remove the data-role="listview".

Is there a way to make simple list (unstyled) ?

Why? I just want to make my specific style without overload JQM style ?

Thanks

Here is my code :

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Quick List & Go</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <ul id="categoriesListContainer" data-role="none"></ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#myShoppingList">Shopping List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#anylink">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The generated code :

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul id="categoriesListContainer" data-role="none" class="ui-listview">
        <li data-id="1" data-category="fruits" data-page="products" class="ui-first-child"><a href="#products" class="fruits ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">fruits</a></li>
        <li data-id="2" data-category="légumes" data-page="products"><a href="#products" class="vegetables ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">légumes</a></li>
        <li data-id="3" data-category="viande" data-page="products" class="ui-last-child"><a href="#products" class="meat ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">viande</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So even though I use a data-role="none", a list-view class is generated.

Comment: Have you tried adding: data-role="none"

Comment: Yes and class "ui-content" still present. Any Idea ?

Comment: Try adding data-role="none" to all elements including the LI?

Comment: Can you post your code?  I just tried it in my JQM site and I see a plain list.  Also what version of JQM?

Comment: We really need your code to get this fixed. In this [exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/m4hgdupt/), jquery mobile isn't enhancing the list except  if you ask for it (data-role="listview")

Answer (score 0):

I'm so confused ! All your answers were correct.

I read my code again and see that my

were generated with JS. At the end of my function, I used this code :

```
myUL.listview();
myUl.listview("refresh");
```

All your answers helped me. Thanks to stack community.